# How to generate AutoIncrement number with prefix of financial year?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, auto-increment

My Client wants to generate a code for every ticket number that goes into database based on the financial year they are working (April current year to March next year) and number needs to reset to 0 where the financial year changes

Example:

```
ID
17/18/0000001
17/18/0000002
... 
18/19/0000001
18/19/0000002
...
```

[image]

If the financial year is stored in database like starting an ending month and year. How we can check that this is the next year broda! reset the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't attempt to try and maintain such a counter internally.  Rather, I would generate at the time of querying.  The query below assumes that your table does have a single ordinary auto increment counter `ID` as well as a `year` int column for the fiscal year.  We can use the following to generate the counter you want:

```
SELECT
    RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(4), year), 2) + '/' +
    RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(4), year + 1), 2) + '/' +
    RIGHT('0000000' +
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY ID) AS VARCHAR), 7)
FROM yourTable;
```

## Demo

Comment: I had to use that because i need to generate ticket number as per the fiscal year. As the year cycle changes the ticket number need to be reset

Comment: @InfiRazor Maybe someone else will you give you the answer you want.  An auto increment column _must_ be unique.  So any scheme internal to SQL Server would be fairly complicated, I think.

Answer (score 0):

*Client is always right.* Suppose you have a table

```
create table #trans(
    id int identity(1,1),
    transDate datetime
    --other fields
    )
--the table is filled

declare @dStart date='20160401', --start and end dates 
        @dEnd date='20170331'    --of the first financial year

;with fy as ( -- fill following years
select 1 id, @dStart dStart, @dEnd dEnd
union all
select id+1,DATEADD(year,1,dStart),DATEADD(year,1,dEnd)
from fy 
where id<5 --"majic" 5 is arbitrary
)
select  dStart,dEnd,t.*, 
    right(cast(year(dstart) as varchar),2)+'/'+right(cast(year(dEnd) as varchar),2)+'/' -- F.Y. label
    + FORMAT( ROW_NUMBER() over(
         partition by right(cast(year(dstart) as varchar),2)+'/'+right(cast(year(dEnd) as varchar),2)+'/' --restart numbering each F.Y.
         order by t.id),'000000') ticket
from fy
inner join #trans t on cast(t.transDate as date) between fy.dStart and fy.dEnd
```

And have what the Client wants.
**Disclaimer:** If some data are deleted then ticket numbering change.